# Encrypting Joda Date combined with username as a single variable

Tags: java, spring-mvc, encryption, jodatime

I am working in a Spring-MVC application and for password reset function, i am sending an email, which contains the username+Joda Date. Before sending it, I would like to encrypt the content(date+username) in such a way that they can be perfectly reversed. As far as my theoretical understanding goes, doesn't reversing defeat the purpose of encryption in first place? If not, then I would like to encrypt them and then some mechanism to decrypt them. There are some solutions I found, one of them mentions retrieving but I cannot figure out which entity is which. I am pasting the code below. Kindly have a look :

Encryption and decryption :

```
byte[] userBytes = username.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
//XOR scramble
byte[] encrypted = new byte[userBytes.length];
for(int i = 0; i < userBytes.length; i++){
   encrypted[i] = (byte)(userBytes[i] ^ keyBytes[i % keyBytes.length]);
}

BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
String encoded = encoder.encode(encrypted);

// webappB, decode the parameter
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decoded =  decoder.decodeBuffer( encoded );
//XOR descramble
byte[] decrypted = new byte[decoded.length];
for(int i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++){
   decrypted[i] = (byte)(decoded[i] ^ keyBytes[i % keyBytes.length] );
}
```

Comment: The question is what type of attack you might want to prevent when using encryption. Note: XOR is a very bad idea if you don't change the key for every link that you send out.

Comment: I can also use Calender if JodaTime is so much problem while encryption as I just want to check if the time difference is less then 24 hours.

Comment: Ok, encryption would make the whole thing stateless, but do you want it? If not, why not just saving the current or maximum allowed time in the database and comparing when the reset request comes in?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am looking to find some middle ground, where it is not too complex to implement but guarantees enough security.

Comment: Neither username nor timestamp are particularly secret, right? You could create a token that contains both together with some kind of signature (HMAC). That way you can prevent/detect tampering and yet easily read the data. I can post some sample code if you're interested in this approach.

Comment: @MarkoŽivanović : Sure, Just one question before you take efforts, where does te HMAC signature come from?

Comment: Your web application would generate the token in the form username:timestamp:hmac and the hmac would be calculated based on username and timestamp. Also, secret key needed for HMAC would be either hardcoded in the source or supplied some other way (database, ...). When you receive the token from the user, you take username and timestamp, calculate HMAC using the same secret key and compare to the HMAC in the token. If they don't match, token is either damaged or was tampered with.

Comment: That sounds good...Can you post the code which you have...And what do you mean by take username, wont I be able to extract that from the token itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class has two public methods, one for generating token and another for validating it. It is abridged from much larger and more complex code, so, some errors might be introduced. There are also some tests embedded, so you can play with it immediately. Any way, I hope it will be sufficient to get you on the right track.

```
package tokens;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class TokenUtils {

    private static final String HMAC_ALGO = "HmacSHA256";
    private static final String TOKEN_SEPARATOR = ":";
    private static final long MAX_AGE = 1_000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // 24h

    private TokenUtils() {
    }

    public static String createToken(String username, long timestamp, String secretKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(generateTokenStringPublicPart(username, timestamp));
        sb.append(TOKEN_SEPARATOR);
        sb.append(computeSignature(username, timestamp, secretKey));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static boolean verifyToken(String token, String secretKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String[] parts = token.split(TOKEN_SEPARATOR);
        boolean result = false;
        if (parts.length == 3) {
            String username = parts[0];
            Long timestamp = Long.valueOf(parts[1]);
            String signature = parts[2];
            if (signature.equals(computeSignature(username, timestamp, secretKey))) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp < MAX_AGE) {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String generateTokenStringPublicPart(String username, long timestamp) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(username);
        sb.append(TOKEN_SEPARATOR);
        sb.append(timestamp);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String computeSignature(String username, long timestamp, String secretKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(generateTokenStringPublicPart(username, timestamp));
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), HMAC_ALGO);
        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_ALGO);
        hmac.init(sks);
        return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(hmac.doFinal(sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String secretKey = "secret_key";
        String token = TokenUtils.createToken("marko", System.currentTimeMillis(), secretKey);
        System.out.println(token);
        System.out.println("Original token verification: " + TokenUtils.verifyToken(token, secretKey));
        token = token.replaceAll("a", "b");
        System.out.println("Tampered token verification: " + TokenUtils.verifyToken(token, secretKey));
        token = TokenUtils.createToken("marko", System.currentTimeMillis() - 1_000 * 60 * 60 * 48, secretKey);
        System.out.println("Expired token verification: " + TokenUtils.verifyToken(token, secretKey));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.its late here...i will try it first thing tommorrow morning.

Comment: Thank you, that code helped a lot. Just one question, any advice regarding the Secret key, like how should I generate it, I was thinking using UUID.randomUUID();..

Comment: If you change the key, all tokens signed with the old one become invalid, so, it would make sense to keep it the same. I'd generate some good long-ish random string (e.g. `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1k count=1 | sha512sum` on linux) and just hard-code it. Makes it virtually impossible to just randomly guess.

Comment: Done. Thank you very much again. That will be all. Incase if I run into some error, I will just comment here.

Comment: Hello, I am just having a tiny problem : Base64.getUrlEncoder() doesn't resolve, as I am using Java 1.7. Any ideas what other method I can use for Java 1.7. I am using Maven too if that is important to know.

Comment: Sorry, this code works on Java 8. Java 7 doesn't have base64 codec, so, you can use commons-codec. Add commons-codec dependency (groupId commons-codec, artifactId commons-codec, version 1.10) to your pom.xml and replace encoding call with `Base64.encodeBase64String(...)`

Comment: Thank you, I already did. Although as elegant and awesome your solution is, the JSP file is unable to take the complete token as a parameter. I have raised a question regarding the same, please dont forget to have a look :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063057/jsp-page-url-not-parsing-email-address-as-a-parameter

Comment: I hope you checked that question, this token generating mechanism wont work as it also creates '/' in token and it is interpreted as sub-url by the application.

Comment: Should be an easy fix, just replace `Base64.encodeBase64String(...);` with `Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(...);`.

Comment: That is how I had did it, but why is .com not getting interpreted?

Comment: Can you please check this question related to encryption, Thanks a lot , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810059/spring-mvc-on-the-fly-encryption-decryption-for-2-columns-in-db