# JSP page url not parsing email address as a parameter

Tags: jsp, encryption

I am working on a Spring-MVC application, and I am working on the password reset functionality. The token which is sent to user is created in 3 parts, Email-id : timestamp : secretkey.. So for example, when I tried to test the password reset link and pasted the url I recived in email(given below). I copied the token parameter in a field, anything .com is ignored? Why is that happening? Any solutions.

Reset link Url :

```
localhost:8085/newpassword/myemail@gmail.com:1416404954901:uXRjA7FAqe0bO_zdwse_4PdVzjQdT1RjJ3QYG5PEODg
```

JSP page saves it as :

```
localhost:8085/newpassword/myemail@gmail
```

resetpassword.jsp page :

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/newpassword/{token}" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="username">
                    <spring:message text="username"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="username"  />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="token">
                    <spring:message text="token"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="token"  />
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="newpassword">
                    <spring:message text="newpassword"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="newpassword"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/resetpassword")
    public String newPasswordPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        return "resetpassword";
    }
   @RequestMapping(value = "/newpassword/{token}")
   public String changePasswordFunction(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, Model model, @PathVariable("token") String token){
        if(person.getPassword() == null){
            return "resetpassword";
        } else {
            personService.changePassword(token,person.getUsername(),person.getPassword());
            System.out.println("User and password is :"+person.getUsername()+" and password "+person.getPassword());
            model.addAttribute("person",person);
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
```

Token creation mechanism :

```
 @Override
    public void createToken(String username){
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1_000 * 60 * 60 * 48;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(generateTokenStringPublicPart(username, timestamp));
        sb.append(TOKEN_SEPARATOR);
        try {
            sb.append(computeSignature(username, timestamp, signKey));
        } 
      // The above method returns the String as :
return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(hmac.doFinal(sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

I pass that link to the email id of the person. Any solutions? I tried using MD5, it works perfectly as its just integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the token through [URL encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html). It should properly escape all problematic characters, so that encoded token can be passed as part of the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, / and all are removed, but anything from .com is not visible, When the user is opening the link : localhost:8085/newpassword/akshay@gmail.com:1416411570349:d7v6_sxF9VfCMqBnvBmje6HiDdbYN_R1a4lXAyluEoQ , then token value is only akshay@gmail...Any idea what is the problem with ".com" in the string

Comment: I just checked by adding a user as akshay@gmail and the token gets passed perfectly. Still got problem with .com

Comment: Have you tried using URLEncoder to wrap the token? Because it will encode `@` as `%40` and then it should work.

Comment: I am encoding it like this: URLEncoder.encode( Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(hmac.doFinal(sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))); . And I am having problem with '.com', not '@'.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated) seems to be related.