# Spring MVC : On the fly encryption/decryption for 2 columns in db

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, encryption, cryptography

- I am working on a Spring-MVC application which uses Hibernate as the ORM and PostgreSQL as the database, in which I am looking for
  on-the-fly encryption decryption solution, but only for 2 columns in
  the database, the rest all can stay non-encrypted. I have a Person
  entity, which has a password and I am encrypting the password with
  BCrypt and saving them in database.

  - If possible, I would like to use this password to encrypt/decrypt
    those 2 columns once the user logs in and does action on those 2
    columns.
  - As I am using Spring-Security too, I am injecting the encoder bean so
    Spring-Security can login the user.
    Here is how I am saving the password and my security-application-context. As I am just starting with this problem, not that much progress to paste here :

Person entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{


@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "person_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq_gen",sequenceName = "person_seq")
private int id;

 @Valid
    @Email
    @Pattern(regexp = emailRegexp)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

@Valid
@NotEmpty(message = "Password may not be empty")
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
```

// getters and setters ommitted
 }

PersonServiceImpl :

```
  @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean addPerson(Person p) {

        Person existingUser = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(p.getUsername());
        if(existingUser == null) {
            this.personDAO.addPerson(p);
            p.setAccountstatus(false);
            p.setOnetimeemail(false);
            p.setUsername(p.getUsername().toLowerCase());
// as you can see I am encrypting the password and saving in DB, I don't know how to access the plain password at this point to use in some algorithm for on-the-fly encryption/decryption
            p.setPassword(BCrypt.hashpw(p.getPassword(), BCrypt.gensalt(11)));
            p.setUsername(p.getUsername().toLowerCase());
            this.personDAO.addPerson(p);
            sendAccountActivationEmail(p.getUsername(), p.getFirstName());
            return true;
        } else {
            return  false;
        }
    }
```

Security-application-context.xml :

```
<beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
               <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Any pointers, help would be nice. If there is anything unclear, kindly let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please note, I am also looking for a solution, where if the user changes his/her password, then I should be able to decrypt and re-encrypt all the values again. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: bcrypt is not encryption algorithm, in the sense that there is no decryption. It is used to safely encode user password. Once you have bcrypt hash, you can only verify whether user-supplied password, using the same salt, encodes to the same hash. It is impossible to reverse the hash into original password.

Comment: @MarkoŽivanović Can you suggest me any other strategy with which I can take the user password and use it as a key for encrypting and decrypting those 2 columns? Thanks a lot.. :-)

Comment: I would think along the following lines: when you create new user account, generate strong, random password and use that for encryption/decryption. You can use regular encryption (e.g. AES-GCM) using bcrypt hash as the key for storing this "master" password in DB. That way you can just re-encrypt the master whenever user changes his password and not all the records encrypted with the master.

Comment: @MarkoŽivanović : Let me get this correct. So when a user inputs a password say "abc123", I use one of my own strong,randomly generated key and encrypt the above password and save it in db...Correct?

Comment: More something along the lines of: generate random master key, encode "abc123" using bcrypt/scrypt, encrypt master key with bcrypt hash and use master key for all data encryption operations. Of course, this scheme is not particularly secure, depending on your requirements: how sensitive is the data you are protecting and who are you protecting it against.

Comment: @MarkoŽivanović : That is not what I am looking for, that would make the master key susceptible, we are looking to avoid data theft from admins and developers. So the user password is the only one I can think of.

Comment: If your software can use available data to decrypt sensitive information then your developers/sysadmins will be able to steal it as well. The only (relatively) reliable way to solve this is to use [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) for key storage and decryption.